# Why is detail lost when computing shadow and reflections in my ray tracer

Tags: c++, graphics, raytracing

I am building a ray tracer and I am able to correctly render diffuse and specular parts of my sphere.  When I come to calculate shadows and reflections however I end up with a very pixelated result as shown in the below image:

[image]

I can see that the shadow is cast in the correct place and if you zoom in the reflection is also visible but again pixelated. I call this method to determine if a pixel is in shade and it is also called recursively by my reflect ray method to determine the reflected colours.

```
    RGBColour Scene::illumination(Ray incidentRay, Shape *closestShape, RGBColour shapeColour, Ray ray)
{
    RGBColour diffuseLight = _backgroundColour;
    RGBColour specularLight = _backgroundColour;
    double projectionNormalToSource = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < _lightSources.size(); i++)
    {
        Ray shadowRay(incidentRay.Direction(), (_lightSources.at(i).GetPosition() - incidentRay.Direction()).UnitVector());

        Vector surfaceNormal = closestShape->SurfaceNormal(incidentRay);

        //lambertian shading.
        projectionNormalToSource = surfaceNormal.ScalarProduct(shadowRay.Direction());

        if (projectionNormalToSource > 0)
        {
            bool isShadow = false;

            std::vector<double> shadowIntersections;

            Ray temp(incidentRay.Direction(), (_lightSources.at(i).GetPosition() - incidentRay.Direction()));
            for (int j = 0; j < _sceneObjects.size(); j++)
            {
                shadowIntersections.push_back(_sceneObjects.at(j)->Intersection(temp));
            }

            //Test each point to see if it is in shadow.
            for (int j = 0; j < shadowIntersections.size(); j++)
            {
                if (shadowIntersections.at(j) != -1)
                {
                    if (shadowIntersections.at(j) > _epsilon && shadowIntersections.at(j) <= temp.Direction().Magnitude() && closestShape != _sceneObjects.at(j))
                    {
                        isShadow = true;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!isShadow)
            {
                diffuseLight = diffuseLight + (closestShape->Colour() * projectionNormalToSource * closestShape->DiffuseCoefficient() * _lightSources.at(i).DiffuseIntensity());
                specularLight = specularLight + specularReflection(_lightSources.at(i), projectionNormalToSource, closestShape, incidentRay, temp, ray);
            }
        }
    }
    return diffuseLight + specularLight;
}
```

As I am able to correctly render the spheres apart from these aspects I am convinced the problem must lie within this particular method so I have not posted the others.  What I think is happening is that where the pixel values retain their initial colour instead of being shaded I must incorrectly be calculating very small values or the other option is that the calculated ray did not intersect, however I do not think the latter option is valid otherwise the same intersection method would return incorrect results elsewhere in the program but as the spheres render correctly (excluding the shading and reflection).

So typically what causes results like this and can you spot any obvious logic errors in my method?

**Edit**: I have moved my light source in front and I can now see that the shadow appears to be correctly cast for the green sphere and the blue one becomes pixelated.  So I think on any subsequent shape iterations something must not be updating correctly.

**Edit 2**: The first issue has been fixed and the shadows are now not pixelated, the resolution was to move the break statement into the if statement directly preceding it.  The issue that the reflections are still pixelated still occurs currently.

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between temp and shadowRay? When you calculate an Intersection is the rays direction normalized? If not I would check `shadowIntersections.at(j) <= temp.Direction().Magnitude()` again. [This](https://github.com/CantTouchDis/ElTrazadoDeRayos/blob/master/src/RayTracerLib/materials/ShadowMaterial.cpp) is how I implemented shadow a while ago.

Comment: There is no difference between temp and shadowRay, I added temp in to help debug and have forgotten to take it out.  The direction of the ray being tested is normalised when calculating the magnitude.

Comment: One more thing: I think the break should be inside the if statement. But I'm still not sure what your `shadowRay` does. Is it the ray from the light to the intersection?

Comment: ^ this.  As soon I read it I saw it, thanks!

Comment: Can you write an answer with the working code? It might help others.

Comment: Will do, I will tidy it up a bit first so it is a more helpful answer.

Comment: The solution is oversampling, 8x or even 16x is often needed to produce adequate results. You need to be rendering those at much higher resolution to avoid loss of detail.

Comment: @ddriver Oversampling is only a cure for *aliasing* artifacts. The artifacts in question, however, stem from incorrect code, not from aliasing. You can't cure incorrect code by averaging it out, a bias would remain.

Comment: The construction of the shadow ray looks suspicious to me. I'd have expected calculation of the intersection between `incidentRay` and an object, and then taking that point and the location of the lightsource to construct the shadow test ray. I certainly would not expect the direction of the incident ray to be of importance.

Comment: @cmaster - oversampling when calculating raytracing, not everything. Matte reflection/refraction might even require more to look good.

Answer (score 1):

Pixelation like this could occur due to numerical instability. An example: Suppose you calculate an intersection point that lies on a curved surface. You then use that point as the origin of a ray (a shadow ray, for example). You would assume that the ray wouldn't intersect that curved surface, but in practice it sometimes can. You could check for this by discarding such self intersections, but that could cause problems if you decide to implement concave shapes. Another approach could be to move the origin of the generated ray along its direction vector by some infinitesimally small amount, so that no unwanted self-intersection occurs.